# 鶏肉【とりにく】? 鶏肉【けいにく】? 鶏肉【ちょうにく】? チキン? for chicken meat

Tags: word-choice, usage, food

Others have asked about "chicken meat" in general, but I do not see any answer to this question: what is the *usage* difference between:

鶏肉【とりにく】, 
鶏肉【けいにく】, 
鶏肉【ちょうにく】, 
and
チキン?

Thanks.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29419/difference-between-%e3%83%93%e3%83%bc%e3%83%95-and-%e7%89%9b%e8%82%89

Comment: Are you sure you saw 鶏肉 as ちょうにく?

Comment: I don't think 鶏 can be read ちょう. Maybe you're confusing it with 鳥, which can be read ちょう, no? (We don't read 鳥肉 as ちょうにく, though)

Comment: This is where I found the pronunciations https://jisho.org/search/%E9%B6%8F%E8%82%89

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Japanese.
I often use "鶏肉(とりにく)" and チキン.

[けいにく or とりにく](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/102.html)
Please read here.
Both readings are correct, but in general, people will read “とりにく”.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the two pronunciations represent geographical preferences, but とりにく seems to be the one used by national media. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The reading of 鶏肉{とりにく} or 鶏肉{けいにく} seems to have explained in the other answer. And, 鳥肉{ちょうにく} should be read as 「とりにく」.

So long as I know 鶏肉{とりにく} implies only chicken meats you usually buy at supermarkets in your neighborhood.

鳥肉{とりにく} implies "Duck meat" : 鴨肉{かもにく}, "Turkey" : 七面鳥{しちめんちょう}, "Chickens" : 鶏{にわとり} for sure, in rare case, "Sparrow" : 雀{すずめ} cooked as Yakitori, etc.

The poultry, which is not common other than chickens, is sold at wholesale market. 
Probably you can buy cooked Turkey at any supermarkets even convenience store before Christmas.

I imagine 「チキン」 is chicken meat cooked as "Fried Chichken" ; "Kentucky Fried Chicken" :「ケンタッキーフライドチキン」or「[モスチキン](https://www.mos.jp/menu/detail/220001/7/)」; "Broiled Chicken, Teriyaki Chichken" : [照り焼きチキン](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%85%A7%E3%82%8A%E7%84%BC%E3%81%8D%E3%83%81%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNSHjYz1qZ_T1jTBz1rBg5uMkFNvOw:1570979699913&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_rtm3w5nlAhXvyosBHfODCpgQ_AUIESgB&biw=1440&bih=826). So, its food texture is normally tender or crispy.